# Android Studio "app" module directory keeps appearing collapsed on open

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Ever since updating to Studio v3.5, I've noticed that the `app` module keeps appearing collapsed only during **startup/restarts** (as opposed to Gradle sync/builds, where I had a bunch of directories/packages expanded within the `app` module from previous cached sessions) for some reason as shown in the attached image below.

I'm now starting to wonder if there's a particular config setting I can set to resolve this issue. And no, `Autoscroll to Source` and `Autoscroll from Source` didn't help out here since this only happens once I open up Studio. And also no, `Invalidate Caches & Restart` didn't resolve this issue either.

[I also reported this via Issue Tracker here.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140187803)

[image]

---

**Update as of 11/11/2019**:

**Same results when using the latest preview version (`v4.0 Canary 2` as of writing this)**

Also, as shown in the screenshot below, I was able to confirm that other directories (`buildTools` for some shell scripts in this case) remain open when opening up Studio while the `app` module **still** remains closed. I also updated the Issue Tracker ticket with Google.

[image]

At this point, I'm finding this to be incredibly annoying and counterproductive, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update as of 1/11/2020**:

I finally took the bullet and reinstalled Studio (v3.5.3), but still to no avail... **BUT I did notice that this issue only happens for Git-cloned projects as opposed to newly created projects**. Now I'm starting to wonder which config files (i.e. `workspace.xml`) are responsible for this. Any ideas?

And no, the `.idea` nor `.*iml` files are not included into Git with the exception of `.idea/codeStyles` as that's not gitignored by default. Here's the `.gitignore` file from the cloned project (which isn't really different from a default `.gitignore` file):

```
*.iml
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/tasks.xml
/.idea/gradle.xml
/.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
/.idea/dictionaries
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/caches
# Android Studio 3 in .gitignore file.
/.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
/.idea/encodings.xml
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/navEditor.xml
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing this problem on Android Studio 3.5.3 but only in one project. Old projects and new projects work fine. I also tried to "checkout from version control" for problematic project but it keeps collapsing app module.

Comment: @Marat No solution yet (and I'm currently on v3.5.2) :-( but I'll post the answer here as soon as I find out! :-)

Comment: @Marat - as posted in the answer below, upgrading to the latest stable version of Studio (v4.0) worked for my existing git-cloned project FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like updating to the [latest and greatest stable version of Android Studio v4.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?authuser=1#4-0-0) did it for me as the solution may have been included in one of the many bug fixes this release!